# Groupby each column in a for loop and print bar plots in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, pandas-groupby

I have seen similar questions.. But mine is different because I want to do things in a for loop, and I get unexpected behaviour.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['1', '0', '1', '0'], ['Male', 'Female', 'Female', 'Male'], ['LabelX', 'LabelY', 'LabelY', 'LabelX']]).T
df.columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'label']


print(df.groupby('label')['col2'].value_counts().unstack(0).plot.barh())
print(df.groupby('label')['col1'].value_counts().unstack(0).plot.barh())
```

SOMETIMES my graphs get printed one below another, with some weird alignment issue but atleast they get printed. OTHER TIMES they may not get printed at all.. I would simply get

```
AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.77)
AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.77)
```

with no plots whatsover

This is a smaller dataset, for many categorical columns like the ones above after careful data cleaning to ensure that the columns of type `object` don't have other mixed types, I would like to run a for loop like so:

```
for col_name in df.columns:
    if col_name != 'label':
        print(df.groupby('label')[col_name].value_counts().unstack(0).plot.barh())
        print()
```

The above code is supposed to work.. Prints plots sometimes, sometimes not.. Can't figure out what's happening.

Basically, I would like to run a for loop, create a bar graph grouped by my column `label` like in the example DataFrame and just view the frequency. But like I said, the plots may or may not print.. I don't care about how the bar plots look.. I just want to group by category and have bars showing frequency counts for my label in each category.. I also don't care what library it is that you're using

Comment: why are you printing the plots? When you print `AxesSubplot(..)` is the expected output.

Comment: On a jupyter notebook, I see not only `AxesSubplot(..)` but sometimes also the bar graph itself. sometimes when I use `print`, sometimes without `print`

Comment: What is different between "sometimes" and "sometimes not"? I suppose you may want to explicitely set the backend: `%matplotlib inline`. I would however recommend not to `print(plot())`. Instead `plot()` whatever you want to, and in addition `print()` any text you want to appear.